# 3D Medical implant designing and Printing - Perfect Adaptation to Surface with Complex Geometry

Tags: snapping

I want to make a patient specific implant for 3D Printing. I have the stl model of the patients mandible and i have designed the basic shape of the implant.

I need the Implant thickness to be 1 mm even thickness.

[image: This is the stl from the patients CT data made with 3D Slicer]

[image]

[image: This is the implant design]

First and Second picture is the mandible from the CT data made from the 3D Slicer stl model.

Third Photo is the concept implant which needs to be 1 mm thickness.

Fourth photo is the implant adapted to the mandible. I need the inner surface of the implant to adapt perfectly for to the contours of the mandible surface and have 1 mm even thickness after adapting perfectly for 3D printing.

How do i make this implant inner surface adapt perfectly to the surface of the mandible. Then have 1 mm even thickness for 3D Printing. I tried boolean with difference but the thickness become uneven when i use it.

[image: Implant adapted to the mandible]

Edited.

the shrinkwarap does the trick. But i only want one part of the implant to adapt to the surface.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need a shrinkwrap modifier on the plane, targeting the mandibule, then after that you use solidify modifier with 1mm thickness (turn on high quality normal too). Make sure your plane has plenty of geometry to shrinkwrap onto the mandible, do so by adding a subdivision modifier before the shrinkwrap if necessary.

If the shrinkwrap act weirdly try decimating the mandible a little bit with a decimate modifier since it's very high poly and might glitch the shrinkwrap.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. The shrinkwrap works well after i subdivided the mesh and solidify it later. But the entire mesh get the modification. Is it possible to only shrinkwrap only selected part of the object. Becuase i only want to adapt only one part of the wall. Other part needs remain the same. I have updated my question with a new photo of the way i want this. Please be kind enough to help me in this.

Comment: It's possible to to assign only some vertices of the mesh to a vertex group and then use the modifier only for the vertex group.